# Lists of small lattices and posets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

Does any one know where I can find a table that lists, up to isomorphism, all the lattices for a set with small order? and the same thing for how many posets can be formed from a set with small order. I have spent an hour trying to find such a table online but with no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Peter Jipsen maintains some lists of small ordered algebraic structures, including a nice page/applet that generates Hasse diagrams of all finite lattices with at most 7 elements [here](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/gap/).  (Some of the links on that page seem to be broken right now. I emailed Peter to let him know.  Hopefully they will be fixed soon.)  There are also diagrams of all connected posets of size 4 and 5 [here](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/gap/posets.html).

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but if you need larger listings:

**Lattices:** Available for $ \le 16$ elements [here](https://researchdata.edu.au/catalogue-unlabelled-lattices-16-elements/1355270), by V. Gebhardt and S. Tawn. With $n=16$ the count is $1\,471\,613\,387$. In fact they have [listed lattices of up to 20 elements](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2018.10.017) but for $n>16$ the listings are inconveniently large to publish.

**Posets:** Available for $n \le 10$ elements [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/digraphs.html), by B. McKay. With $n=10$ the count is $2\,567\,284$. If you need more, you can use a C program by B. McKay and G. Brinkmann's to list them yourself.  One version of their poset-listing program is available [here](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/14110) (yes, it's an arcane location).

For very small orders you can just use SageMath's "Posets(n)", but it is quite inefficient for $n \ge 8$, unless they have improved the algorithm in a later version.